# Changing root variables from withing a function in AS 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm new to Actionscript 3, just started working with it after years of working with AS2,

What I'm trying to do at the moment is to change a variable that's located in the root from a function,

Something like this:

```
var myVariable:String = "String test";

function testFunction():void
{
 myVariable = "new String";
}
```

I know this is problematic, I've tried to google about it a lot, about getters and setters, global variables and such, but I'm still having trouble with this, I'd be glad to understand why this doesnt work and how to actually do this.

Thank you

EDIT:
I'm trying to load an XML file with a list of books,
I looked around and found this function, tried to adjust it to work for me, but I cant get this to work,
I'm able to load the XML and actually read the info from it, but I was trying to set a global array or something like that so I can access the data later,

heres the code:

```
var books:XML = loadBooks();
trace(books); //Returns a blank output

function loadBooks():XML {
    var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var xmlData:XML = new XML();
    xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadXML);
    xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("bookList.xml"));

    function LoadXML(e:Event):void {
    xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
    trace(xmlData); //Returns what I want to have
    }

    return xmlData;
}
```

Comment: That snippet on it's own will work fine, as long as you call the function after the variable is defined.  How are you testing it?  I guess there is actually more to this that you're not showing?

Comment: @shanethehat yes there is more to this actually, I edited the question with what I'm actually trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is caused by the asyncronous nature of loading in AS3.  In your loadBooks function you set up a listener to detect the load complete event, but your code doesn't stop there.  It carries merrily on while the load in in progress, meaning that you actually return an empty XML object.

This is how you should do it:

```
//define the variable in wide scope
var books:XML;
//start the load operation
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var xmlData:XML = new XML();
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadXML);
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("bookList.xml"));
//event handler for load complete
function onLoadXML(evt:Event):void
{
    //clean up the listener
    xmlLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadXML);
    //assign the XML to your books object
    books = new XML(e.target.data);
    trace(books);
    //call a function to use the loaded data
    readBooks();
}

function readBooks():void
{
    ...
}
```

Once your application becomes dependant on the results of a load operation, you will have to wait for the load event, and have the handler for that event trigger the next step in your program's execution.  I have illustrated this with the readBooks function.

You could wrap the actual load operation in a function as well, but keep the load function and the event handler separate.

Also, by convention function names should start with a lowercase letter, so I renamed your handler function accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the great answer, it was very helpful, I now understand what the problem was, and it now works just like I wanted it to!

Answer (score 0):

instead of root to refer back to the stage, as3 has changed the communication back:

```
MovieClip(parent).nestedMovieClip;
```

The above applies for variables aswell

```
var bob:int = 0;
MovieClip(parent.parent).bob = 3;
```

inside the movieclip:calling back to parent or to root/stage this variable is changed 
 :: now bob = 3,

the above will work, any problems google"as3 root in as3:;

or else let us Know give me your code and i will work it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I edited the question, I hope that I made myself clear